# Could not find design.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I try to build an apk it fails with this error:

```
> Could not find multidex.jar (com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.jar
> Could not find design.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/27.0.0/design-27.0.0.jar
> Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar
```

I checked the [JCenter status](http://status.bintray.com/) it's working properly.

So Why it fails?

UPD

The same code used to build a couple of days ago!

here is the project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/reactnative/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with project level build.gradle?

Comment: Updated with project level build.gradle.

Comment: Can you add `jcenter()` as last statement in both `repositories{}` and `google()` as first?

Comment: @Sagar it worked! I'd appreciate if you gave any explanation.

Comment: Great! I have provided some explanation in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.android.support:design:27.0.0` is not available in `jcenter()` repository but in `google()` repository. Looking at your error logs, looks like Android studio is trying to find it in `jcenter()`. To enforce it to look inside `google()` make `google()` as your first statement or place it above `jcenter()` in both `repositories{..}` blocks.

```
repositories {
    ...
    google()
    jcenter()
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know why gradle can't search into others declared repositories in stead of only the first one?

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce I suspect, there could be case that `jcenter()` has older version of a library and cannot match it with latest version. `google()` has latest version of libraries hence it can resolve correctly.

Comment: Thanks you saved my day!